# Iframe load everything after receiving postMessage content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

I have an iframe that receives some information trough a contentWindow.postMessage function to it can login into a page that i am also making. however the i am assuming the page loads before the contentWindow.postMessage message shows up. How do i load the page AFTER the domain receives the information?

here is the code.

Page with the Iframe:

```
<template>
    <iframe
        id="iframe" 
        name="iframe" 
        src="http://localhost:8081/login" 
        frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"
        >
        ></iframe>
</template>

<script>
    let show = true;
export default {
    
  name: 'appFrame',
    
    function(){ document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage({
      userData: { 
        info1: localStorage.info1,
        info2: localStorage.info2,
        info3: localStorage.info3
        }}, 
      'http://localhost:8081/list');
      },
  data () {
    return {
      //
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

this is the window.onmessage on my other page that i want to load with the information:

```
window.onmessage = function(event)
{
  if(event.origin == 'http://localhost:8080')
  
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = event.data;
  localStorage.setItem("info1", event.data.userData.info1);
  localStorage.setItem("info2", event.data.userData.info2);
  localStorage.setItem("info3", event.data.userData.info3);

  console.log("LOCALSTORAGE: ", localStorage.getItem("info1"), localStorage.getItem("info2"), localStorage.getItem("info3") )

};
```

How would i go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your second application (running at http://localhost:8081) is Vue.js application, you would have the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.origin == 'http://localhost:8080') {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = event.data;
    localStorage.setItem("info1", event.data.userData.info1);
    localStorage.setItem("info2", event.data.userData.info2);
    localStorage.setItem("info3", event.data.userData.info3);

    console.log("LOCALSTORAGE: ", localStorage.getItem("info1"), localStorage.getItem("info2"), localStorage.getItem("info3") )
  }
});
```

In a typical Vue.js application, the root instance needs to be created. The initial code is something like:

```
const rootInstance = {
  data() {
    return { /* Declare reactive properties */ };
  },

  methods: {
    attemptAfterLogin() {
      // do something here.
    }
  }

  template: `<div>Hello App</div>`
};

const app = new Vue(rootInstance);
```

The goal here is to put this initialization code inside the `message` event handler. Combining this into one code, it will be:

```
const rootInstance = {
  data() {
    return { /* Reactive properties */ };
  },

  methods: {
    attemptAfterLogin() {
      // do something here.
    }
  }

  template: `<div>Hello App</div>`
};

// Initialize Vue.js app
const app = new Vue(rootInstance);

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.origin == 'http://localhost:8080') {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = event.data;
    localStorage.setItem("info1", event.data.userData.info1);
    localStorage.setItem("info2", event.data.userData.info2);
    localStorage.setItem("info3", event.data.userData.info3);

    // Mount the application
    app.$mount(document.querySelector("#app"));

    // Tell the Vue.js app that localStorage is now set.
    app.attemptAfterLogin();
  }
});
```

This is just one way of doing things. Also, till the time your inner iframe receives the message, you can have a simple loader animation.

On a side note, prefer `addEventListener` over `onmessage` when listening for events.

> In a nutshell, irrespective of the front-end framework, the goal is to have a single entry point/function to load your application.

Comment: what do you mean by  "root instance" exactly?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, every Vue.js application usually has one top-level component. That is a root instance. Read more [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html).

Comment: so the my one top level component would be my app.vue? because he is the one with my routerview that redirects to everything.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, it can happen. There will be other things that you might want to look into. Such as vue-router behavior with iFrame, multiple initialization sequence, etc.

Comment: what if we do it like this. How do i keep trying to send the date until the iframe window receives it and sends an information back?